# Agrupar dos segmentos en una ruta

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente consulta en donde se muestran un origen, un destino y el segmento correspondiente:

```
    SELECT APD Orígen, APA Destino, CONCAT(CONCAT(APD,'-'),APA) Segmento FROM KE.Vuelos2 
WHERE YEAR(CAST(KE.HRZMX(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(SDDP AS varchar),1,4),'-'), CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(SDDP AS varchar),5,2),'-')),
CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(SDDP AS varchar),7,2),' '), CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(STD AS varchar),1,2),':')), SUBSTRING(CAST(STD AS varchar),3,2))) AS datetime)) = 2021
AND MONTH(CAST(KE.HRZMX(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(SDDP AS varchar),1,4),'-'), CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(SDDP AS varchar),5,2),'-')),
CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(SDDP AS varchar),7,2),' '), CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(STD AS varchar),1,2),':')), SUBSTRING(CAST(STD AS varchar),3,2))) AS datetime)) = 5
AND DAY(CAST(KE.HRZMX(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(SDDP AS varchar),1,4),'-'), CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(SDDP AS varchar),5,2),'-')),
CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(SDDP AS varchar),7,2),' '), CONCAT(SUBSTRING(CAST(STD AS varchar),1,2),':')), SUBSTRING(CAST(STD AS varchar),3,2))) AS datetime)) <= 31
GROUP BY APD, APA ORDER BY 1,2
```

Y los resultados se muestran de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que yo quisiera es agruparlos por Ruta y no por segmento, es decir, para los segmentos MEX-ACA y ACA-MEX la ruta sería ACA-MEX. Para los segmentos GDL-MEX y MEX-GDL la ruta correspondiente sería GDL-MEX.

Cómo se puede observar, en el nombre de la ruta predomina el orden alfabético del segmento. No comprendo muy bien cómo realizar la agrupación. ¿Cómo podría resolver éste inconveniente?

Comment: Ignorando lo que hace la función `KE.HRZMX()`, creo que tu clausula `WHERE` puede quedar simplificada como `WHERE SDDP BETWEEN 20210500 AND 20210531`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma de hacerlo, es usando CROSS APPLY y un constructor de tabla de valores (la sentencia `VALUES`). Con eso podemos aplicar MAX y MIN a los valores para poder ordernarlos.

```
SELECT ord.Origen, 
       ord.Destino, 
       CONCAT(ord.Origen,'-',ord.Destino) Segmento 
FROM KE.Vuelos2 
CROSS APPLY( SELECT MIN( AP) AS Origen, 
                    MAX(AP) AS Destino
            FROM (VALUES(APD),(APA))x(AP))ord
GROUP BY  ord.Origen, 
          ord.Destino 
ORDER BY Origen,
         Destino;
```

La alternativa parece más sencilla a primera vista, pero se vuelve más problemática entre más se use.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
        CASE WHEN APD < APA THEN APD ELSE APA END AS Orígen, 
        CASE WHEN APD < APA THEN APA ELSE APD END AS Destino, 
        CASE WHEN APD < APA THEN CONCAT(APD,'-',APA) ELSE CONCAT(APA,'-',APD) END AS Segmento 
 FROM KE.Vuelos2
 GROUP BY APD, APA
 ORDER BY Orígen,
          Destino;
```

Aunque pordría simplificarse un poco con una CTE.

```
WITH cteVuelos AS(
     SELECT CASE WHEN APD < APA THEN APD ELSE APA END AS Orígen, 
            CASE WHEN APD < APA THEN APA ELSE APD END AS Destino
 FROM KE.Vuelos2
)
SELECT  Orígen,
        Destino,
        CONCAT(Orígen, '-', Destino) AS Segmento
FROM cteVuelos
GROUP BY Orígen,
         Destino
ORDER BY Orígen,
         Destino;
```